# Color Android splash screen using theme

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin Forms Android app, I would like to change the color of the splash screen based on a theme that the user has selected at run time. This change should impact the next run of the app.

I have tried using the built in splash_screen.xml and using a Splash.axml file, but I cannot figure out how (if possible) to set the background color of the splash screen to a color defined in a theme.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all of the research I've done and the things I've tried in code, I am concluding that it is not possible to dynamically set the color of the initial activity. I am going with a neutral color for the splash.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using the built in splash_screen.xml and using a Splash.axml file, but I cannot figure out how (if possible) to set the background color of the splash screen to a color defined in a theme.

You can define themes for your splashScreen and then set `android:windowBackground` to a specific color:

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppTheme2">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
  ...
</resources>
```

SplashScreen.cs( don't forget to set SplashScreen activity to be mainlauncher):

```
[Activity(Label = "SplashActivity",MainLauncher =true)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ISharedPreferences preferences=GetSharedPreferences("SplashThemeId", FileCreationMode.Private);
        var themeName=preferences.GetString("themeName","AppTheme");
        int themeId = Resource.Style.AppTheme ;
        switch (themeName)
        {
            case "AppTheme":
                themeId = Resource.Style.AppTheme;
                break;
            case "AppTheme2":
                themeId = Resource.Style.AppTheme2;
                break;
        }
        SetTheme(themeId);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
```

As you noticed, I use `SharedPreference` to store the user selected Theme in Runtime. You can also use [Android Settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) for the same purpose.

Here is the complete [demo](https://github.com/elvisxia/ThemeSplashDemo). It's native android project, but it's the same for forms project.